# Read Context Information Asynchronously with Fiware Context Broker

Tags: php, curl, websocket, fiware, fiware-orion

I am using Context Broker in order to read measures from my sensors.
Until now, I have to refresh my application's web page in order to read the latest measures.

How could I update the measures on my page without refreshing it?
Is there any way to use curl get request with polling or websockets?
Or is there an operation that Context Broker provides in order to update asynchronously the new measures that my sensor sends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pretty easy to implement what you are asking for ...
How do you get the data from Orion in the first place?
With a `GET /v2/entities` perhaps.
Just program a call to Orion in a javascript function (a bit of Ajax) triggered by a setInterval and then change the values of your fields of your web page. Right?

Comment: Yes but the interval should be set with the time period at which my sensors send a new measure?

Comment: Without websocks, you wont get subscriptions, so you will have to use polling. How frequently do you want to poll? That I cannot answer. Just be careful not to load the broker too much.  Once per second should not be a problem.  
However, your problem was that you wanted to avoid to have to refresh the browser manually, right?

Comment: My Sensors send a new measure every minute.I would like to save my measures on a database to be able to read statistics and to update the content of my web page every time the CB catches a new measure.In addition,the measures should be saved on the database even though i don't watch the web page.Which should be the best solution to succeed both operations?

Comment: I thought to make a php file running as cron job which make get requests on CB and saves every new measure on a DB.Then i make an ajax call and read the latest measure which has been saved on my db and refresh the UI.Is it a correct thought?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly I think that there is not such a thing in Fiware Community and. However I think that you could implement that behavior without pain starting from this:

**Orion and Suscription Mechanisim**

Orion Context Broker use a subscription mechanism that is well explained in [this](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv2/#subscriptions) section of official documentation.
Starting from that you could subscribe your App to specific changes on your device's contexts and then receive new data each time a devices send a new measure.

However this is not enough to receive notifications in your Web Application from client side. To do so you must suscribe your application backend and then implement an asynchronously mechanism to notify the client from your backend using for example *Websockets* as you correctly said.

**NGSI Proxy**

In the other hand there is [this](https://github.com/conwetlab/ngsi-proxy) component from FIWARE community called NGSI Proxy that implements a similar logic for you and could be of some help for you. I confess that I only use it in the past indirectly using a Wirecloud Widgets and I am not sure if it is the answer for your problem.

I'm sorry if it could not be enough help.

Answer (score 0):

Orion implemented websocket support time ago (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305740/subscriptions-via-websockets-in-orion)) but it was as an experimental proof-of-concept that at the end hasn't landed in the master repository branch (at least up to the present moment ;)

You could have a look in order to see if it suits your problem. However, an Ajax-based alternative, as @kzangeli is points out in his anwers, seems to be a priori more feasible.